# Why can't the Backstack be popped after naming the transaction

Tags: java, android, fragment-backstack

After adding Transaction to backstack and giving it name it isn't popped after `popBackStack(name, flag);` or `popBackStackImmediate(name, flag);` is called, but when calling `popBackStackImmediate();` it is popped without problem. So why is this happening? What am I understanding falsely about popBackstack method?
The Code:

Adding the Transaction:

```
fr.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new Community()).addToBackStack("exerciseToDiscuss").commit();
```

Popping the Transaction:

```
fr.popBackStackImmediate("exerciseToDiscuss",0); or  fr.popBackStack("exerciseToDiscuss",0); -> same Result no pop


fr.popBackStackImmediate();-> works fine
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `beginTransaction()` at all if you are using Navigation. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There is an exercise overview Fragment inside of Activity there is a button which when clicked takes the user to community page where he can discuss the exercise,once the user is finished he can go back but he can also click on the bottom menu and open up other fragments which are then added to backstack,I would like that if the user decides not to goBack but checks out other fragments that the transaction is overwritten once the user decides to click on the same button again.Ideally  would like to remove the transaction completely once the user clicks on the menu to checkout other fragment